# Bash-Shell script show source code, not html

Tags: bash, shell, cgi

It's weird that my shell script in website show the whole source code, not the html that I want.
My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

cat << EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
        <title>test</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="../jquery/css/redmond/jquery-ui-custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[


        if(verifiedUser == "")
            window.top.location.href = "/";


        //]]>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table align="center">
            <tr><td align="right">Product Name</td><td align="left">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td align="right">Hardware Version</td><td align="left">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td align="right">Firmware Version</td><td align="left">

            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
EOF
```

and what the .cgi file show is just that code!
My cgi file is in the same directory of the html files, because the main directory is in /mnt, so not put in /home/www/cgi-bin/ as usual.

What's the reasonable problem can cause this situation?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like the server isn't running the script, it's just returning it as a static file. Are you sure the server is configured to run `.cgi` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmar has the right idea - Your server is very likely not configured to run those files, but rather send the file directly to the client. So it's a configuration issue, not a programming one.

Comment: Thank you guys! I notice that the original file that my co-worker gave me can run the cgi, so maybe the problem is that I changed the original file not properly, so that the cgi cannot be run :O

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the separator between header section & the html data should be a blank line [in `CRLF` format](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html).

Try this:

```
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\r"
echo -e "\r"

cat << 'EOF'
---remaining HTML data---
EOF
```

Note: I have also changed `cat << EOF` to `cat << 'EOF'` to prevent any variable expansion. Revert it if variable/command expansion is needed.